# Finder Menu Services No Longer Working

Tags: applescript, macos, automator, services

In Pre-Yosemite, I had some finder menu services (i.e. Right-Click, see 'Services' in menu, hover over, and you'd see Services created in Automator) that I made. As a developer, these were very handy as I'd often have to rename a *large* amount of files to some criteria (i.e. removing/replacing/adding text). I can make services fine now, and even get them to work *within* Automator (dragging and dropping the file(s) into Automator). However, if I right-click the file(s), hover over 'Service' and select my service, it ***never*** runs. In fact, if I check `Activity Monitor`, I see 'Automator Runner' just hanging there (one for each time I try). I have tried restarting and logging out and in. This doesn't fix it.

Note: I am running OS X Yosemite.

Comment: May be a good idea to show what you have in the Automator actions!!

Comment: @markhunte For testing purposes, I made a service that simply does 'Copy Finder Items' to 'Desktop'. Doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it. I had a dozen Automator Runner tasks not responding in Activity Monitor and I had to kill one to get the services to work again. This probably was a different issue than yours, since even restarting didn't fix it.

Comment: I've noticed the ScriptMonitor is hanging when I try to run my Automator based services. If I quit it when its process hangs, the Automator script runs.

Answer (score 1):

Open and re-save your services in Automator.

This will update them to work with Yosemite, and also warn you of any incompatibilities with the actions you're using in the services.

As a side note, this definitely should be something you're notified about when trying to run an old service, but at least you don't need to re-create new duplicate services.